# How to use the values as indices to create a matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a vector matrix V [m x 1] containing values between 1 and n, I need to use these indices to create a matrix M [m x n] of 0 and 1 where the 1 would be at the index indicated by V, for each row.

Example:

If V is:

```
[
1,
2,
4]
```

then M should be:

```
[
1, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eye(4,4)([1 2 4],:)
ans =

   1   0   0   0   
   0   1   0   0   
   0   0   0   1
```

EDIT: Same result with split up statements

```
V = [1 2 4]
I = eye(4,4);
M = I(V,:);
```

Comment: Nested accessing is not supported in MATLAB.  You probably ran this in Octave.  You should probably split this up into two statements so that MATLAB users can run the code properly.  FWIW, the answer is correct.

Comment: My pleasure :)!  FWIW, I wish it did support it.  Sometimes I get annoyed with the extra step.

Comment: It's been a while I used MATLAB but now that it came up I remember being annoyed with it as well.